Struggling with JIRA REST API: How to Dynamically Create Required Fields When Types Differ?
We're facing an issue while using the JIRA REST API to dynamically create required fields in the DOM. The problem arises because the types we get from the API sometimes don't match the actual input types. We're using this API: https://jira.domain.com/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta/ISSUE-TYPE-key/issuetype/ISSUE ID.
How can we deal with this inconsistency and ensure that the types from the API align with the required input types for our dynamic field creation? Any tips or advice would be really helpful. Thanks!
We attempted to use the JIRA REST API (specifically, https://jira.grazitti.com/rest/api/2/issue/createmeta/ISSUE TYPE/issuetypes/ISSUE ID) to dynamically generate required fields in the DOM. Our expectation was that the types retrieved from the API would consistently match the actual input types needed for our dynamic field creation process. However, we encountered a discrepancy where the types sometimes differed, leading to compatibility issues.
